# Turn a Pandas Dataframe into undirected edgelist

Tags: python, pandas

Given a data frame of edges, I would like to create an aggregated data frame with a column "frequency" that contains the total edges between two nodes.  I would also like the edge list to be undirected, so if there is A => B = 1,  I would also like to have a row such as B => A  = 1.

## Original Data

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['jane','jane','jack','bill','jack','terra'],
                     'y': ['jack','jack','jane','terra','terra', 'jack']})

     x      y
0   jane   jack
1   jane   jack
2   jack   jane
3   bill  terra
4   jack  terra
5  terra   jack
```

## Expected Output

```
       x      y  frequency
0   jane   jack          3
1   jack   jane          3
2   bill  terra          1
3   jack  terra          2
4  terra   jack          2
```

## Tried this

```
## Get size of of one direction for edge list
data=data.groupby(['x','y']).size().reset_index() 

## rename column to 'frequency'
data.rename(columns = {0:'frequency'}, inplace = True) 

## copy dataframe to calculate other direction of edgelist 
data2 = data.copy() 
## reverse the names of columns
data2.rename(columns = {'x':'y', 'y':'x'}, inplace = True) 
## merge
data2 = data.merge(data2, left_on=['x','y'],right_on=['x','y'], suffixes = ['1','2']) 
## add the frequency to get total edge strength
data2['frequency'] = data2['frequency1']+data2['frequency2'] 
data3 = data2[['x','y','frequency']]
 
       x      y  frequency
0   jack   jane          3
1   jack  terra          2
2   jane   jack          3
3  terra   jack          2
```

This final result works somewhat well and I'm not concerned with order of rows. But the problem is, I am missing a row for Bill and Terra. Due to how I merged, it was lost since i originally only had bill => terra without a terra=> bill, so the row was discarded.

I'm wondering how I may identify rows that will be discarded and concatenate them back in, or if there is a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I discovered a method to achieve my desired result. The method uses a nested apply(). First I create the data frame with the frequency column for the cases that will work, already outlined above) which will serve as the barebones to concatenate onto the cases that don't work.

```
## Same steps as before to calculate frequency column

data=data.groupby(['x','y']).size().reset_index() 
data.rename(columns = {0:'frequency'}, inplace = True) 

##Identify which of those cases will not work using a nested apply function. 
Inner loop returns the opposite direction of the edge and outer loop checks 
the sum of all cases where the original edge has another in the other 
direction.
Code these as 0's and 1's, and filter 0 to identify which edges 
need to be manually created and appended to the final result.

remaining_rows = data.loc[data.apply(lambda x: 1 if sum((x['x'], x['y']) == 
data.apply(lambda x: (x['y'], x['x']), axis = 1))>=1 else 0, axis = 1) ==0]
remaining_rows2.rename(columns = {'x':'y','y':'x'}, inplace = True)
remaining_rows = pd.concat([remaining_rows, remaining_rows2])

remaining_rows

      x      y  frequency
0  bill  terra          1

##Create the edges for the other direction and concat

remaining_rows2 = remaining_rows.copy()
remaining_rows2.rename(columns = {'x':'y','y':'x'}, inplace = True)
remaining_rows = pd.concat([remaining_rows, remaining_rows2])

remaining_rows

       x      y  frequency
0   bill  terra          1
0  terra   bill          1

## Yes! This is the piece that I can concat onto the other data frame so 
that I have a complete Edge list with a frequency column for each edge 
A=>B and B=>A.  After concatenating, remember to specify 
reset_index=True
```